# Add Sentry log4j2 appender to Apache storm

Tags: log4j2, apache-storm, sentry

I need to send error log to my sentry server . how can I add a sentry appender to my topology ?

I add log4j2.xml file to my topology class path and set properties *topology.logging.config: log4j2.xml* in crawler-conf and *add -Dsentry.dsn=https://xxx* to *topology.worker.childopts*. it works in my local cluster but when I submit it to storm cluster it does not send log to sentry and throw error *main ERROR Unable to locate appender SENTRY for logger config SENTRY_LOGGER* .

below is my log4j2.xml :

```
<configuration monitorInterval="60" shutdownHook="disable">
  <appenders>
    <Sentry name="SENTRY"/>
  </appenders>
  <loggers>
    <Logger name="SENTRY_LOGGER" level="ERROR">
      <appender-ref ref="SENTRY"/>
    </Logger>
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```